# Using part of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to create a numpy array and then use a range of data within that array.

For example,

```
import numpy as np

x2 = np.linspace(-2,2,100)
for i in range(len(x2)):
    print(x2[i])
```

This prints out 100 numbers from -2 to 2, how would I use this array and just print out values from -2 to 1? I intend to do more than just print the range, this is just a stepping stone to improve my understanding. If it's not possible, how would you recommend going about it?

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple using [masks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays):

```
for i in range(len(x2[x2<=1])):
    print(x2[i])
```

A more idiomatic way is to do:

```
for i in x2[x2<=1]:
    print(i)
```

Or even just:

```
print(x2[x2<=1])
```

Though the latter will print the return value of the `__str__`method of the `numpy.ndarray`, and not each value line by line.